# OutOfMemoryException when trying to display image continuously

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I am trying to display images which i am getting from server side using screenCapture but on client side (Android Emulator) doesn't display any image, after running for a while through exception "OutOfMemoryException". So i need some help. Here is the code.

Server

```
  public class Server
{
  private Connection con;
  private ScreenCapture sp;
  private Socket soc;
  private DataOutputStream out;
  private DataInputStream in;

public Server() throws IOException, AWTException
{
    con = new Connection();
    sp = new ScreenCapture();  
}

public void init() throws IOException, AWTException

{
    con.setPort(3838);
    ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket(3838);
    soc = serversocket.accept();
    System.out.println("Accepted");
    out = new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
    in = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
    while(true)
    {
    sp.CreateScreenCapture();
    out.write(sp.getScreenCapture());
    }

}

public void closeConnection() throws IOException
{
    soc.close();
}

public static void main(String[] arg)
{

        Server server = null;

    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            server = new Server();
            server.init();

        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }
        catch (AWTException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                server.closeConnection();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

    }


}
```

}

Client

```
  public class UpdateScreen extends View
{

private DataInputStream input;
private DataOutputStream output;
private Socket soc;
private Bitmap image;



public UpdateScreen(Context context) throws UnknownHostException, IOException 
  {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    init();
}

public void init() throws UnknownHostException, IOException
{

    soc = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.2"), 3838);
    input = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
    while(true)
    {
    byte[] img = this.getByteArrayFromStream();
    image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length);

    }

}


protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) 
   {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, w, h, false);

    }


public byte[] getByteArrayFromStream() throws IOException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int nread;
    byte[] data = new byte[1042];
    while((nread = input.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1)
    {
       buffer.write(data, 0, nread);    
    }

     return buffer.toByteArray();
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    invalidate();
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The server sends images continuously and the client tries to receives all data (an infinite amount) before it would even start to draw.

Better would be e.g. a polling approach, meaning that the client requests a new image and the server delivers a single one.

There would remain some problems yet: Server must send length of image data (or close connection after each image) so that client knows when it should stop waiting for data and start processing and onDraw() shouldn't call invalidate() because this can lead to too often or too seldom further calls to onDraw() (if it would work at all).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ImageView's to diplay the images, you probably dont need the huge images as-is the server is sending.

You can probably do couple of things:

1. Use a library like Aquery and associate its ImageLoading to your view
2. Do the hard work yourself - refer Android docs - Displaying Bitmaps efficiently

Comment: i am not using image view i am drawing directly on canvas using

Comment: If the server is under your control then probably you can scale it down there itself,if not, couple of other things/pointers (1) Scale down the image while its still at InputStream level - refer my point 2 above, (2) Bitmaps at ARGB_XXXX are very heavy clear them off as soon as possible (3) if you cant do both and want to get this off quickly try using a webview and a photo gallery plugin to add effects, might be much more simpler (4) how about changing the UI pattern a bit, like showing the user  a smaller version first and then the larger version (5) if all fails and you still need it...

Comment: .. try exploring render script for computation, there's not much documentation and it can get tricky (6) I'm hoping you have already set your manifest to use LARGE_HEAP